# iPhone: Three20 Framework Integration Problem

Tags: iphone, three20

I've added Three20 using this command:

```
python three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p path/to/myProject.xcodeproj -c Debug -c Release Three20
```

as described in http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project

Everything works fine and there are no errors in the Terminal.

Now when I build the Project in Xcode, I'm getting the following error:

```
File /Users/xxx/Desktop/facebook-three20-b253114/src/Three20/../../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20.a depends on itself.  This target might include its own product.
```

And it's the only error. What's the **meaning** of this error ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error myself by following the Steps 1 & 2 of tut: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-photo-gallery-three20/